# Displaying multiple input boxes inline

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to have these 3 input boxes inline on my webpage. "Leave Code" &  "From" I was able to bring inline. However the "To" input box remains on the next row.

I believe this has to do with the  tag I am giving "To". Not sure how to fix this

I have tried using some basic CSS. Attached is my code snipped

```
<div class="Dates" *ngFor="let dateline of dates">
      <!--         
        <div class="ui-g">
          <div class="ui-g-12"> -->
      <div class="ui-g form-group">
        <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
          <p-dropdown [options]="leaveCodes2" [(ngModel)]="selectedLeaveCode2" placeholder="Leave Code"
            optionLabel="name"></p-dropdown>
          <div style = "display: inline-block; padding: 2rem ">
          <h3 >From</h3>
          <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date3" [showIcon]="true" showTime="true" hourFormat="12"></p-calendar></div>
          <h3  style = "display: inline-block; padding: 2rem ">To</h3>
          <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date3" [showIcon]="true" showTime="true" hourFormat="12"></p-calendar> <br><br>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the view:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can force the situation with a little help of css:

```
<div class="ui-md form_inline">
    <div class="ui-md-2">
       <label>First Item label:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-md-2">
       First Value
    </div>
    ...
<div>

<style>
.form_inline > .ui-md-2{-ms-flex: 0 0 16.6666%!important;  flex: 0 0 16.6666%!important;  max-width: 16.6666%!important; float:left!important;}
</style>
```

You can check how is the size of box adding:

```
    <style>
.form_inline > .ui-md-2{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
```

If you have div.ui-md-2 at 100% width, probably you have a hack in css that change that. It's better fix this with a particular class and don't change this columns for whole project. 
:D

Answer (score 0):

Keep simple:
Use  for labels,
Don't use h3 for subtitles:
If use div, h#, p, etc all this elements are display in block.

```
<div class="ui-md">
    <div class="ui-md-2">
       <label>First Item label:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-md-2">
       First Value
    </div>
    ...
<div>
```

Comment: Even removing the h3 tag and setting a label, I am still unable to get all 3 fields inline